# Stretch/Distortion. I have a large monitor, and it makes Ubuntu look so ugly

Tags: laptop, screen

I have a fairly bad machine, but it does what I need it to do.

I have a Compaq Presario All-in-One - CQ1-2025, and it is a 20" monitor. It's a cruddy machine, as I said, but all I need it for is for web browsing, so it does what I need it to do.

Link [http://dicksmith.com.au/product/XC8894/compaq-presario-cq1-1210an-all-in-one-desktop#Specification](http://www.google.com/products/catalog?q=Compaq%20all%20in%20one&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-a&cid=1145487001478452779&os=tech-specs) if you want to check it for yourself.

If it's my Graphics Card, I have an Intel® Graphics Media Accelerator 3150.

However, I've been wanting to upgrade to Ubuntu for a while now. The past 3 times I've tried it;

Two out of Three times I had to do a whole system reboot on my computer, shortly after restarting my computer, for the first time after I installed Ubuntu.

One out of Three times I had to manually restart my computer because Ubuntu and my computer locked up for over 20 minutes.

Three out of Three times I had to manually restart my computer continuously during the installation of Ubuntu, on account of it crashing during the installation. It just stopped responding.

On top of it all, I was repulsed by the way Ubuntu looked on my monitor. On Windows, when you have a larger monitor, it just expands everything. On Ubuntu, it tries to fill it all in, and as a result, it looks very stretched, distorted, and very low quality on my computer. I'm not sure if this is only me, but it just looks very horrendous on my monitor.

I will be getting a new laptop for school next week, however, which only has a 12" display. I can try it on there, and see if I get the same problem.

If this isn't only me, or you have a solution that could help me fix Ubuntu in my current predicament, please reply and/or answer my question.

TL;DR
I have a large monitor (20 Inches), and Ubuntu stretches to fill it in. Any way to fix it?

Comment: This sounds like a graphics driver issue - what is your graphics card?  type lspci | grep VGA and copy and paste the output into your question.  Also if you have a file /etc/X11/xorg.conf - please add this to your question.  If you have added any graphics drivers in "Additional Drivers" windows - details of that would be useful.

Comment: @fossfreedom I don't have Ubuntu installed at this time, but I do remember from past experience what it looks like. And; You're going to laugh at me when I say this; Intel® Graphics Media Accelerator 3150. If you want to see the full specs, look here. http://dicksmith.com.au/product/XC8894/compaq-presario-cq1-1210an-all-in-one-desktop#Specification

Comment: Have you tried the alternate CD for a non graphical installation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is coming from the fact that while intel supports Linux well, they don't do the same with resolution on Linux (I know from experience). It is frustrating but I'm not sure if you can work around it. Possibly adding something to the xorg.conf file to set a custom resolution could do it, but in the past I've had rather mixed results (sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't).

Your best bet (may) be to use the latest Ubuntu version when it's available (11.04 is out now, but 11.10 will be here soon). Newer drivers might_just_work with a higher resolution.

On your 12" system you won't have that problem btw.